# Replace string in file, if exists with Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a file, containing a single line of multiple space separated strings:

```bash
$ cat /tmp/strings.txt
alpha beta gamma zeta omega
```

My goal is to check if `delta` string is not present inside /tmp/strings.txt, and if not, add it after `gamma` string:

```bash
$ cat /tmp/strings.txt
alpha beta gamma delta zeta omega
```

What I think would be a solution:

```bash
    - name: Check if delta string is present
      ansible.builtin.command: grep 'delta' /tmp/strings.txt | wc -l
      register: delta_string

    - name: Add delta string
      ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
        block: gamma delta
        path: /tmp/strings.txt
      when: delta_string.stdout == 0
```

Is this a proper use of string replacements in Ansible? Not sure how `ansible.builtin.blockinfile` block works, will it insert the `gamma delta` string if is not found, as replacement for `gamma`, or will it add it at the end of file?

Is there a solution which does require a `when` check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I understand that you like to have a file with a single line of "text" only.

Since Ansible is a Configuration Management Tool with which you declare the Desired State, that is all what you would need to do. There is no need for any CHECK IF THEN INSERT (ELSE) WHEN contruct.

For an input file of

```bash
~/test$ cat strings.txt
alpha beta gamma zeta omega
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Make sure lineinfile is in Desired State
    lineinfile:
      path: strings.txt
      line: alpha beta gamma delta zeta omega
      regexp: '^alpha' # or even '^alpha beta gamma zeta omega'
```

will result into an output file

```bash
~/test$ cat strings.txt
alpha beta gamma delta zeta omega
```

**Further Documentation**

- [`lineinfile` module – Manage lines in text files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html)

  > *This module ensures a particular line is in a file, or replace an existing line ...*

Most likely would work too

- [`template` module – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html)

Answer (score 1):

Put the twins into a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
  twins:
    gamma: delta
    foo: bar
```

Read the file and split the items. Declare the variable

```yaml
  strings: "{{ out.content|b64decode|split() }}"
```

The task below

```yaml
    - slurp:
        src: /tmp/strings.txt
      register: out
```

gives the list of the strings

```yaml
  strings: [alpha, beta, gamma, zeta, omega]
```

Iterate *strings* and add the twins if missing

```yaml
  update_str: |
    [
    {% for i in strings %}
    {% if i in twins and strings[loop.index]|d(None) != twins[i] %}
    {{ i }}, {{ twins[i] }},
    {% else %}
    {{ i }},
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    ]
```

gives valid YAML

```yaml
  update_str: |-
    [
    alpha,
    beta,
    gamma, delta,
    zeta,
    omega,
    ]
```

Convert the string to the list

```yaml
  update: "{{ update_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  update: [alpha, beta, gamma, delta, zeta, omega]
```

Join the items and write the file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/strings.txt
        content: "{{ update|join(' ') }}"
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/strings.txt 
alpha beta gamma delta zeta omega
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    twins:
      gamma: delta
      foo: bar

    strings: "{{ out.content|b64decode|split() }}"
    update_str: |
      [
      {% for i in strings %}
      {% if i in twins and strings[loop.index]|d(None) != twins[i] %}
      {{ i }}, {{ twins[i] }},
      {% else %}
      {{ i }},
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      ]
    update: "{{ update_str|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - slurp:
        src: /tmp/strings.txt
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: strings
    - debug:
        var: update_str
    - debug:
        var: update
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/strings.txt
        content: "{{ update|join(' ') }}"
```